# R: read.table and missing values

Tags: r, na, read.table

When I load my data file in tab delimited format in R, I got this error message:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 3 did not have 5 elements
```

Here's my data:

```
KEY ID      code1   code2   name
1   sadsa   32423   344     ffsadsa
2   vdffsfs 21344   234     fsadfgg
3   3e4dsa  21321   #N/A    #N/A
4   dcxzc   23421   #N/A    #N/A
5   xzzcc   21223   124     erfsacf
6   sdas    21321   464     fsadfsa
7   assdad  32132   455     fsadfda
```

I can see that the error is caused by the "#N/A" value in my data. I have tried the read.table option such as na.strings or comment.char = "#" but it still did not work.

Is there any ways to keep the actual text (#N/A) or at least replace it with N/A when loading the data in R?

Comment: In the `read.table`, you can specify `na.strings = "#NA"`

Comment: Yes @akrun. I have tried this ->   data = read.table("raw.dat", header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote = "", row.names = NULL, na.strings = "#NA"). It still pops out the error message "
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 3 did not have 5 elements".

Comment: if it is `#N/A`, use that specific value.  I commented earlier by omitting the `/`

Comment: Hi @akrun. Have changed to this ->  data = read.table("raw.dat", header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote = "", row.names = NULL, na.strings = "#N/A"). Still the same error message.

Comment: You may also have to set the argument `comment.char = ""` to stop `"#"` being interpreted as a comment.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use the read.table function with fill= TRUE.

```
read.table(file =file, sep = sep, fill=TRUE)
```

If this does not work, I would suggest to try the readLines function instead of read.table.

```
readLines(...)
```